# Vim listchars showing end of line when there is no newline char

Tags: vim, newline

Create a new text file with notepad, type in 'hello world' and do not press enter at the end. Save the file.

This file has no newline character at the end of the file. Hex editor confirms this.

Yet opening the file in Vim, and turning on `set list`, the `listchars` shows the eol character. Why? Bug?

I've googled and I understand why Vim chooses to automatically write eol chars, and that I can turn that off using `set nofixeol`. But that is irrelevant to this.

The question I have is:

How do I get Vim to only display newline chars that actually exist in the file? Clearly `listchars` does not do this

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google, the answer to my question is, its not possible:

https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6119